# Push Notification Pros & Cons

Tags: web-applications, push-notification

Please help me if anybody can. I am writing a technical document on Push Notifications in Native apps and Web Apps. I want to write pros and cons of push notification in android/iphone  and that of web apps also. I have searched various documents on the web but I am not getting many pros and cons.
Till now I have written - It is cheaper to send a push notification than a SMS or MMS.

Thanks

Comment: You're not behaving well in terms of using StackOverflow. Your reposting the same question. If you're not getting a good answer I would suggest changing your approach. You could also put a bounty on the question to try and get results.

Comment: bro believe me my both questions are not same. It has different meanings in context which I want to write. Thanks for the help bro. anyways Sorry to ask.

Comment: There are a number of issues with how you're asking the question. Please read this for tips: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx By the way, even if it was written more clearly, your question would be considered argumentative and therefore not a good fit for SO's format.

Comment: Thanks bro. Will never commit the same mistake again.. Thanks
Sorry for this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See

[Push vs. pull notification on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585336/push-vs-pull-notification-on-iphone)

Additional thought:

"At both events, Forstall stated that push notifications were a better means to maintain battery life than background processes (which are used for pull technology) as far as receiving notifications are concerned"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service