# Difference between Push Notification and Pull Notification?

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

DO anyone know what is the difference between "Push Notification" and "Pull Notification"?

I know "Push Notification" is C2DM, but I dont have any Idea that what is "Pull Notification"

Anyone pls help..

Comment: its just another name for polling i hope

Comment: polling is the process of checking for any updates to a sever in perodic/non periodic intervals

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585336/push-vs-pull-notification-on-iphone - check this you may get some idea, Android (best of my knowledge) dont have pull notification, we can make web service call based on timer interval

Comment: in short in c2dm the server notifies client of on any msg and in pull the client asks the server @ intervals wether any msg is available

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Push**

Push notifications are a type of **technology** for sending data to phones (pushing).  An example would be an SMS message.  See also WAP, Push email, etc.

The opposite of this technology is usually referred to as "**polling**" where the phone will periodically ask a server for new information or content.

**Pull**

"Pull notification" is usually the term used to refer to the **graphical** representation of a notification or event.  This is displayed in the area at the top of Android phones.  This is the place the user sees a visual "cue" that something has happened.

Other terms related to this are "pull down menu", "drop down notifications" etc

Comment: The pull answer is not correct. See the answer below.

Comment: That is not what pull notifications are. Pull notifications is when the client request the notifications from the server, instead of the server pushing the notifications to the client. For example when you go to the notifications page in Twitter and refresh it, you're "pulling the notifications" from the server.

Answer (score 68):

I have to publish this answer because the accepted one is terribly misleading.

- **[Pull notification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology)** means **a client requesting a server** to check
  if there are any updates.
- **[Push notification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology)** means **a server notifying a client** about the updates.

Comment: I don't know why the other answer is accepted, this is clearly the perfect answer.

Comment: Simply the best answer! This one should be accepted.